# SqlServerReportingServices (SSRS) Character reference "&#

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2014

We have created some report template (RDL file) and it's working fine for some of the clients.

But one client is getting issue while processing the report through web service.

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; colu
mnNumber: 149133; Character reference "&#

We already added XML version and encoding type.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:cl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">
        **Content of report**
</Report>
```

What could be the cause and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: I think that error is referring to the data in the file, not the XML itself. Have you got any sort of data quality checking in your datasource? might be pulling in null numbers or something that hasn't been correctly handled

Comment: Yes, the problem was in data, not RDL file.We got access to client data and in his table, one cell was containing BOM character which was getting read by Report as the parameter list. Thanks.